# Network problems with Hyper-V on Surface Pro 2 running Windows 10 Pro

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, hyper-v

I have set up Hyper-V to test software and duplicate some work environments without compromising my own personal Surface Tab. I am getting confused with communicating between the Host and the VM depending on how I am connected to the Internet. I use either a Realtek USB GbE Family Controller for LAN or Marvel Avastar 350N for WiFi.

I have managed previously to get communication working with the wifi controller by bridging to the VM External adapter, I have set static ip on the VM but I'm getting errors trying to bridge the LAN to VM and just receive destination host unreachable without a bridge.

I'd really appreciate an explanation of the best way to communicate between the host and vm across the different adapters, I don't have extensive networking knowledge and think I am just complicating my problems, any suggestions or links to 'How to's...' greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to build the network connection between Host and VM which running on that host , you just need to create an internal virtual switch , then , configure IP address for VM (assuming it is 192.168.1.2) .

Also configure IP address (assuming it is 192.168.1.3) for Host VNIC (open "Network And Sharing Center" you may find a NIC contains the name of the above Internal virtual switch ,such as vEthernet(xxx) ) .

Last step , connect VM to that internal virtual switch .
Please try to ping each other (notice the firewall setting , you can disable firewall for test ).

> > I'd really appreciate an explanation of the best way to communicate between the host and vm across the different adapters

If you mean , VM needs to use specific physical NIC (Binding another physical NIC to external Vswitch ).

In this case , It depends on the physical network infrastructure . If WIFI IP addresses and LAN IP addresses are routable or in same subnet then VM can access Hyper-v host . If not ,they can not access each other .

[This article](http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/the-hyper-v-virtual-switch-explained-part-1/) introduced hyper-v virtual switch .

Comment: The link to the hyper-v switch guide will be very useful. I have managed to get communication to work by connecting to my wifi rather than Ethernet, I don't understand why but hopefully further reading will help - cheers.